# Higher Order Component (lit-html)

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-html, high-order-component

I am working on a web component library with **lit-HTML** and **haunted**.
I need to create a HOC because I want to update the props before passing them to my component.
I tried some stuff, it's working well.

```
const hoc = (WrappedComponent) => (props) => {
  // here I update my props with a custom hooks
  const newProps = useProps(props);
  return WrappedComponent(newProps);
};
```

but now, "this" is undefined in my component.
I try to bind "this" but nothing works. "this" is still undefined

If someone already tried to create a Higher Order Component? can you share me some example, pls

Comment: Is `WrappedComponent` a functional or class component?

Answer (score 0):

> but now, "this" is undefined in my component. I try to bind "this" but nothing works. "this" is still undefined

The problem with `this` seems to be that you're using an arrow function there (or maybe in your `WrappedComponent` definition that you pass to `hoc` as a parameter). You can't bind `this` for an arrow function, it is always inherited from the parent scope. If you want to have bound `this` (either explicitly or from the calling scope) you need to convert to non-arrow function. Not sure if you have some other problem in addition to this one, but this will probably get you forwards.

It depends where exactly you are trying to use `this`, on where you might need to convert away from arrow-function but here's an example of how you'd do it for the code you shared. You might still be ok using an arrow function in one or both of these cases depending on if you need to call `this` here or not.

```
const hoc = function (WrappedComponent) {
  return function (props) {
    // here I update my props with a custom hooks
    const newProps = useProps(props);
    return WrappedComponent(newProps);
  };
};
```

Can you share a piece of code from the context of where your `this` is undefined?

For more info see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#arrow_functions